# Saving Excel Files to a Specific Path with Unique Filenames

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am working on a function which generates some information, opens an Excel file called "Template.xlsx," and then re-saves that document with a user specified name.

I want a unique name because I want to do this a number of times and so generate multiple files in the same folder. Initially when I was running this and I was just saving with the same name it was fine. But now that I am specifying the file path e.g. path_str = "C:\user\name\" and concatenating that to the user specified name path_final = path_str + file_name + ".xlsx" I am having problems.

I believe the problem is in path_str where the backslash is being interpreted as an escape, so I tried it using two backslashes and that doesn't seem to work either e.g. "C:\\user\\name\\".

So can any one suggest a way of creating the file path string and concatenating it to the user specified filename, so that I can save files in the same path with different user specified names.

Below is the code experiencing the issue:

```
 string_path = "V:\\Staff\\Chris\\Programming\\"
    extension = '.xlsx'
    string_final = string_path + sheet_name +  extension
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(string_final)
```

Comment: Have you tried using [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)?

Comment: Please post some code so that we can have a look at what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks wwii I just tried and am getting No such file or directory: 'V:\\Staff\\Chris\\Programming\\template1.xlsx'

Comment: Stijn Van Daele I have added code

Comment: Thanks wwii, os.path.join did work there was just another issue in my code